# From a python dictionary how do I save the key and value to a *.txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, python-datamodel

How do I print the key and value to a *.txt file from a dictionary?

I have tried to read the data and to print it to a *.txt file but the name.txt file is empty.

```
#The code that I have tried
#my_dict is given above
def create_dict():

    with open("name.txt", "w+") as f:
    for key, value in my_dict:
            print(key, value)
            f.write('{} {}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: That's a bit of a misleading function name. Also, try not to shadow builtin names like `dict` with your own variables. Call it `my_dict` instead. Anyways, where is your `dict` defined?

Comment: I think you need to indent the code after the `with` statement.

Comment: `for key, value in dict.items()` also don't use `dict` since it is a python builtin name

Comment: Additionally, don't `close()` your file on each iteration of the loop; that doesn't make sense. You already have it in a `with` block, so closing is handled for you

Comment: The indentation is impossible. You can't `close` a file you open in a `with` context handler, especially after the first iteration (but it would have written *one* entry before closing ... though without a trailing newline, so the file is not a valid text file).

Comment: Why not just serialize the dict into a JSON file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers pointed out, your indentation is simply wrong inside your `with` statement.

### Pickle

Although, if your goal is to save a dictionary for later use, your best bet is probably to use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). This will not do the trick if your intent is to have the dictionary saved in a human-readable format, but will be way more efficient as a data-storage method.

```
import pickle

my_dict = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'baz': 'spam'
}

# This saves your dict
with open('my_dict.p', 'bw') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_dict, f)

# This loads your dict
with open('my_dict.p', 'br') as f:
    my_loaded_dict = pickle.load(f)

print(my_loaded_dict)  # {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'spam'}
```

### Json

A compromise between storage efficiency and readability might be to use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead. It will fail for complex Python objects which are not JSON serializable, but is a perfectly valid storage method nonetheless.

```
import json

my_dict = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'baz': 'spam'
}

# This saves your dict
with open('my_dict.json', 'w') as f:
    # passing an indent parameter makes the json pretty-printed
    json.dump(my_dict, f, indent=2) 

# This loads your dict
with open('my_dict.json', 'r') as f:
    my_loaded_dict = json.load(f)

print(my_loaded_dict)  # {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'spam'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_dict():

  with open("name.txt", "w") as f:
    for key, value in thisdict.items():
      print(key, value)
      f.write('{} {}'.format(key, value)+"\n")
```

You should rename your dictionary from "dict" to something else (above as thisdict) since dict is a special built in name in Python.